# Customizing the frame title box in Beamer LaTeX

Tags: beamer, presentations, frame-title

I have two questions.

1. For some reason the frame title box is currently transparent, how can I reset this to its default style?
2. Second, I wanted to minimize the height of the box, however this also removes the subtitle. How can I avoid this.

Preamble code:

```
\documentclass[leqno, t]{beamer}

\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usecolortheme{whale}
\useinnertheme{rectangles}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\usepackage{amsthm, amsmath, amssymb, amsfonts, exscale, latexsym, float, eucal, mathtools}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\hypersetup{
    colorlinks = true,
    citecolor = blue,
    linkcolor = black
}

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{%
    \nointerlineskip%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.0ex,dp=1ex]{frametitle}
        \hspace{1ex}\insertframetitle%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
}

\makeatother
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.4\paperwidth, ht = 2.25ex, dp = 1ex, center]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.6\paperwidth, ht = 2.25ex, dp = 1ex, center]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}{Measuring the Natural Rate of Interest}\hspace*{11em}
    \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{0ex}
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}
\makeatletter

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes}  % Required to generate language-dependent quotes in the bibliography
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa, natbib=true, autocite=inline, uniquename=false]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{english}{english-apa}
\addbibresource{References.bib}
\def\citeapos#1{\citeauthor{#1}'s (\citeyear{#1})}
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You don't need `\usepackage{hyperref}` with beamer
- The `CambridgeUS` themes colours your frametitle in a very light gray and the whale colour theme changes the font colour to white. You can change it to the white background and blue font from the default theme or to anything else you like with

  ```
  \setbeamercolor{frametitle}{bg=white,fg=structure.fg}
  ```
- To include the framesubtitle, I suggest following variation of the default frametitle definition:

---

```
\documentclass[leqno, t]{beamer}

\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usecolortheme{whale}

%\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{%
  \ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{frametitle}{}{\nointerlineskip}%
  \@tempdima=\textwidth%
  \advance\@tempdima by\beamer@leftmargin%
  \advance\@tempdima by\beamer@rightmargin%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=0.2cm,left,wd=\the\@tempdima]{frametitle}
    \usebeamerfont{frametitle}%
    \vbox{}\vskip-2ex%
    \if@tempswa\else\csname beamer@fteleft\endcsname\fi%
    \strut\insertframetitle\strut\par%
    {%
      \ifx\insertframesubtitle\@empty%
      \else%
      {\usebeamerfont{framesubtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{framesubtitle}\insertframesubtitle\strut\par}%
      \fi
    }%
    \vskip-1ex%
    \if@tempswa\else\vskip-.3cm\fi% set inside beamercolorbox... evil here...
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
}
\makeatother

\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{bg=white,fg=structure.fg}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{content...}
\framesubtitle{title}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to add room for subtitles?

Comment: @Sean Please have a look at my edited answer

Comment: Great. Quite complex, would not have been able to come up with a solution like that.

Comment: @Sean  if your problem is solved, it would be nice to accept the solution: https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers